# Appium Android: how to swipe through the values in time picker?

Tags: android, appium, timepicker

I am trying to set time in an Android time picker which is of 12 hours format.

I am unable to select AM/PM by clicking or by swiping.

sendKeys() works only for hours and minutes fields and not for AM/PM.

Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is any error message coming ? Which strategy do you use to find AM/PM Element ? Sometimes Appium fails to locate element so try to change your strategy to find element also try Tapping that element.